# Calculate the probability of obtain a red ball from a urn without replacement

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

We have a urn with six red balls and ten green balls.  Two balls are randomly selected in orden from the urn without remplacement. Calculate the probability that the second ball is red.

Because obtain a red ball (R) is a event independent from obtain a green ball (G), we have that
$$P(R_{2}) = P(R_{2}|R_{1}) + P(R_{2}|G_{1})$$
Then, we have that $P(R_{2}|R_{1})= \frac{5}{15}$ because we have the first ball is red, so we had in the urn $15$ balls in total and $5$ are red. Similarly, we have that $P(R_{2}|G_{1}) = \frac{6}{15}$.

Therefore $$P(R_{2})= \frac{11}{15}$$

Am I wrong? I don't think I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is wrong because you forgot to multiply the probability of the what you get as the first ball.
So The Equation Should Be
$$ P(R2)=P(R1)*P(R2|R1)+P(G1)*P(R2|G1) $$
$$      =6/16*5/15 + 10/16*6/15 $$
$$      =3/8 $$

Comment: Mathgeek's answer is correct, but (without the need of any calculations) the symmetry of the system ensures that with 6 red and 10 green balls, if you randomly extract $n<=16$ balls from the container, then for any $m<=n$ the probability that the m-th ball extracted is red will *always* be 6/16 or 3/8.

Comment: I had doubts about multiply by the probabity from the first ball, it is because of the Law of total probabiility?

Comment: Yes @Marinela .  That is the Law of Total Probability: ${P(R_2)= P(R_1\cap R_2)+P(G_2\cap R_2)\\\phantom{P(R_2)} = P(R_1)~P(R_2\mid R_1)+P(G_1)~P(R_2\mid G_1)}$

Comment: **Also:** Every individual ball is just as likely to be the second ball drawn as any other (there is no bias).  Among the sixteen balls, six are red.  Therefore probability that the second ball is red is $6/16$ or $3/8$.  And, Penguino says, this logic works for any position in the draw.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following possible cases

$$RR - RG - GR - GG$$

Your probability is

$$P(RR)+P(GR)=\frac{6}{16}\cdot\frac{5}{15}+\frac{10}{16}\cdot\frac{6}{15}=\frac{3}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $10$ green (G) and $6$ red (R) balls  and there are two ways you can get second ball as red - `GR` *or* `RR`

Probability of `GR` is $\frac{10}{16} \cdot \frac{6}{15} = \frac{1}{4}$

Probability of `RR` is $\frac{6}{16} \cdot \frac{5}{15} = \frac{1}{8}$

So the probability that the second ball is red is,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t we assign the second ball first (6 red balls possible) and then the first ball (15 balls remaining). Then the probability is simply:

$$
\frac{6\times 15}{16\times 15}=\frac{3}{8}
$$